# How can I get array like this

Tags: php, arrays

```
//I have array like below:
$a =array('1,2,6');
$b =array('2,3,1');

//Then I using ArrayCombine :
$arr_combine = array_combine( $a, $b );


//OUTPUT:
//Array( [1,2,6] => 2,3,1 ) ;
```

how can I get array like below?

```
//OUTPUT:
array( 1=>2, 2=>3, 6=>1 );
```

Answer (score 4):

It's taking as complete one string due to your present quotes in arrays,

Should be,

```
$a = array('1','2','6'); // And not '1,2,6'
$b = array('2','3','1');
$arr_combine = array_combine( $a, $b );
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rtlVGQ)**.

And if you can't change the array & have the format like that only see @xdazz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217262/696364).

Comment: @Rikesh you have a point, but what if his array has one string with that format ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the array like that, then you have to explode the element.

```
$result = array_combine(explode(',', $a[0]), explode(',', $b[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

For your second question check like this

```
    <?php

    $x = array( 1 => '2', 2 => '3', 6 => '1') ; 
    $y = array( 1 => '2', 6 => '2' ) ;

    $s = array();

    foreach($x as $key=>$val)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key,$y))
        {
            $s[$key] = $x[$key] + $y[$key]; 
        }
    }

    var_dump($s);

    ?>
```

Try like this

```
    <?php
    $a =array('1,2,6'); 
    $b =array('2,3,1');

    $a = explode(',',$a[0]);
    $b = explode(',',$b[0]);

    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);

    var_dump(array_combine($a,$b));
    ?>
```

Comment: It's work thank you Dev, but I have one thing I got stuck, can you help me one more time?

Comment: @SherAh Glad to know i could help you :)

Comment: **Second question:**

Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [6] => 1 ) ; // array1 has 3 keys and 3 value  1=>2, 2=>3, 6=>1
Array ( [1] => 2 [6] =>2 ) ;// array2 has 2 keys and 2 value 1=>2, 6=>1

I want to array1 and array2 which the same can SUM value: (Ex: array1 "[1]=>2"  and array2 "[1]=>2" into [1]=>4; [6]=>3)  

help me please

Comment: It's possible or not?

Comment: @SherAh Approve answer, if it helped u to solve problem